# Group by key and value for List<Dictionary<string, object>>

Tags: c#, grouping

I have a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` that looks similar to the following:

```
var myList =
            new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
            {
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Name", "Bob" },
                    { "Certification", "Certification A" },
                    { "Date", "10/1/2022" }
                },
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Name", "Bob" },
                    { "Certification", "Certification A" },
                    { "Date", "01/01/2022" }
                },
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Name", "Bob" },
                    { "Certification", "Certification B" },
                    { "Date", "10/5/2022" }
                },
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Name", "Joe" },
                    { "Certification", "Certification A" },
                    { "Date", "10/5/2022" }
                },
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Name", "Joe" },
                    { "Certification", "Certification B" },
                    { "Date", "10/5/2022" }
                },
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Name", "Joe" },
                    { "Certification", "Certification B" },
                    { "Date", "01/01/2022" }
                }
            };
```

I am needing to group by `Name` and `Certification` so that I end up with:

```
{
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Name", "Bob" },
        { "Certification", "Certification A" },
        { "Date", "10/1/2022" }
    },
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Name", "Bob" },
        { "Certification", "Certification B" },
        { "Date", "10/5/2022" }
    },
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Name", "Joe" },
        { "Certification", "Certification A" },
        { "Date", "10/5/2022" }
    },
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Name", "Joe" },
        { "Certification", "Certification B" },
        { "Date", "10/5/2022" }
    }
};
```

I'm completely stumped on how to get to that result so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Why is it `<string, object>` and not `<string, string>`? Can the value be any type? 2) Should it always pick the first date when a "group" has different values for the date?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Yeah, the value can be any type. I just used `string` in my example to simplify it some. It should always pick the most recent date but I can handle that part once I have an idea of how to group them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just leverage the value tuples with their generated equality members:

```cs
var result = myList.GroupBy(d => (Name: d["Name"], Certification: d["Certification"]))
    .Select(g => g.First()) // apply ordering if needed
    .ToList();
```

Or the same with anonymous types:

```cs
var result = myList.GroupBy(d => new { Name = d["Name"], Certification = d["Certification"] })
    .Select(g => g.First()) // apply ordering if needed
    .ToList();
```

Note that this will require all dictionaries to have all members present and all values to correctly implement `Equals` and `GetHashcode`.

Also note that you can type your dictionaries as `Dictionary<string, string>`